# WIx - How to reference a fragment contentained in .wxs file from another fragment

Tags: wix, fragment, wix3.8

I have a wxs file that contains a fragment. The fragment contains a custom dialog. I have another file that contains another fragment. I want to be able to show the dialog from the first fragment in another fragment. I get an error that says Unresolved reference to symbol Dialog:CustomDialog in section fragment.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote but you have no code samples and the question looks more like "do my work for me" instead of a genuine question. You should show what you have, what you tried, where you're stuck.

Comment: if that is how you took the question then you should have gone past it. You have no obligation to do anything. Anyways, I did not understand how the fragments work, I do now, so I answered my own question. Sometimes questions reveal a person's understanding about something but you clearly had no answer or except for smart remarks.

Comment: Again, I didn't downvote your question but that's what I assume whoever did was thinking when they did downvote it. From the information you provided in your question, there's literally no way anyone would know you didn't use the `<Publish>` tag to get your dialog to show up. The only way to have answered your question would be to supply a fully functioning piece of code and explaining how the dialog was added which is way more work than is necessary. In the future you should try to supply more information in your questions. Including both fragments would have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a publish tag

```
<Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="MyDialog"/>
```

No need to reference anything as during the build every fragment becomes part of the main code.